# How do I evalutate the set difference between two heterogeneous sets in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

In (More)LINQ terms how do I do an ExceptBy involving different types?

For example, given the `LeverPosting` structure defined below, an `IEnumerable<LeverPosting>`, and an `IEnumerable<string>`, how do I find all the `LeverPostings` that "aren't in" the `alreadyProcessedIds` list?

```cs
class LeverPosting
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you do something like:

```
IEnumerable<LeverPosting> postings = ...
IEnumerable<string> idsalreadyProcessedIds = ...

var idsalreadyProcessedIds2 = new HashSet<string>(idsalreadyProcessedIds);

var postings2 = postings.Where(x => !idsalreadyProcessedIds2.Contains(x.Id)));
```

Comment: Yeah better with a HashSet so I removed my answer

Comment: Thanks for answering! If memory serves me correctly, doing a `Contains` within a `Where` is orders of magnitude slower than joining on the data. I think I'll write a quick test to confirm what I'm trying to remember. Does using a HashSet make them roughly the same from a time complexity perspective? I wouldn't be surprised if this is how joining in LINQ works under the covers...

Comment: @chase It uses a *Lookup* (see [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ceafecd091387688) and then [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ceafecd091387688)), because it doesn't have a garantee that the second set is "unique", but the principle is the same

Comment: @xantos neat. thanks very much for the link and answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method I came up with to do this:

```cs
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Similar to MoreLinq's ExceptBy method but works on heterogeneous types.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TOther, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sourceItems,
        IEnumerable<TOther> otherItems, Func<TSource, TKey> sourceKeyFunc, Func<TOther, TKey> otherKeyFunc)
    {
        return from sourceItem in sourceItems
            join otherItem in otherItems on sourceKeyFunc.Invoke(sourceItem) equals otherKeyFunc.Invoke(otherItem)
                into gj
            from subSourceItem in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()        // left outer join
            subSourceItem.Equals(default(TOther))            // only items on the left that don't match the set on the right
            select sourceItem;
    }
}
```

Or another extension method based off of @xanatos answer:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Similar to MoreLinq's ExceptBy method but works on heterogeneous types.
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy2<TSource, TOther, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sourceItems,
            IEnumerable<TOther> otherItems, Func<TSource, TKey> sourceKeyFunc, Func<TOther, TKey> otherKeyFunc)
        {
            var otherItemKeyHashset = otherItems
                .Select(si => otherKeyFunc.Invoke(si))
                .ToHashSet();

            return sourceItems
                .Where(oi => !otherItemKeyHashset.Contains(sourceKeyFunc.Invoke(oi)));
        }
```

Usage:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<LeverPosting> ExceptAlreadyProcessed(this IEnumerable<LeverPosting> postings, IEnumerable<string> alreadyProcessedIds) =>
    postings.ExceptBy(
        alreadyProcessedIds, 
        posting => posting.Id,
        alreadyProcessedId => alreadyProcessedId
    );
```

Please let me know if there's a lib like MoreLinq that already does this.

Comment: It turns out that this doesn't work when `DefaultIfEmpty()` returns a value other than null.